# connectDB is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi I'm new to coding currently trying to set up a connection to my server.

Getting an error message:

> "TypeError: connectDB is not a function"

This is my db.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    })

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

module.exports = { connectDB }
```

and this is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const products = require('./seed/products')

dotenv.config()

connectDB()

const app = express()

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running.........')
})
server.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(products)
})

server.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id)
  res.json(product)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} port ${PORT}`)
)
```

Looking for some assistance I'm really new to coding so please forgive me if I posted wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out:

You are exporting `mongoose` from the `db.js` file. Try exporting the function `connectDB` you just created.

```js
// between brackets just in case you need to export something else, ok?
module.exports = { connectDB }
```

Then import it like this:

```js
const { connectDB } = require('./config/db')
```

Comment: Thanks changed it to
module.exports = { connectDB } at the bottom 
and import 
const { connectDB } = require('./config/db')
To server.js

Current error message 
SyntaxError: Identifier 'connectDB' has already been declared

Comment: Ok got it working already thanks! upvoted

Comment: nice to hear it worked @Dave! please don't forget to mark the answer as the one that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    })

    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

module.exports = { connectDB }
```

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const { connectDB } = require('./config/db')
const products = require('./seed/products')

dotenv.config()

connectDB()

const app = express()

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running.........')
})
server.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.json(products)
})

server.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id)
  res.json(product)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} port ${PORT}`)
)
```